# Inequality question (with complex numbers)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-analysis, inequality

I was wondering how would you derive/get $|q(z)|\ge R^2-|a|R-|b|>R^2/2 $?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By application of the triangle inequality, we have
$$|q(z)| = |z^2+az+b| \geq |z^2| - |az| - |b| = |z|^2 - |a||z| - |b|.$$
**Edited: fixed triangle inequality mistake**

Now if we take $R \geq |z|$ and $R$ big enough so that $R^2 \geq |a|R + |z|^2-|a||z|$, we have
$$|q(z)| \geq |z|^2 - |a||z| - |b| \geq R^2 - |a|R - |b|.$$
Then since $R^2/2$ is eventually bigger than $|a|R + |b|$ for large $R$, we can add the negative number $|a|R + |b| - R^2/2$ to the right hand side to get a strict inequality
$$R^2 - |a|R - |b| > R^2 - |a|R - |b| + (|a|R + |b| - R^2/2) = R^2/2.$$
Putting these two pieces is your inequality.
$$|q(z)| \geq R^2 - |a|R - |b| > R^2/2.$$

Comment: Thanks, can I ask why $|z^2+az+b| \geq |z^2| + |az| + |b| $? Because isnt the triangle inequality $|x+y|<|x|+|y|$?

Comment: Dane, you have the first inequality the wrong way round. Ray, a variant of the triangle inequality says $|a+b|\ge|a|-|b|$.

Comment: The variant is the stronger $|a+b| \ge ||a|-|b||$. Since $|x| > x$ for all real $x$, we also have $||a|-|b|| \ge |a|-|b|$

Comment: Sorry about that. How embarrassing. I've edited the answer to reflect your comments.